# update_post_meta is not working for me when I use e.preventDefault for update button

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, jquery

This is the what I'm doing at `WordPress dashboard`.

I'm working on `WordPress plugin`, and trying to save my `input fields` data against the particular product when the `update` button is clicked for the particular `post/product`.

I'm validating those `input fields` , sending an `ajax` request and updating the `post_meta` each time I click on the `update` button.

**Little explanation of what I'm doing**

I'm allowing the user to enter a link for `youtube` , `vimeo` or `dailymotion` video. Therefore I'm having drop-down and other `input` field for `link` where user would select the `type-of-link` (either `vimeo`, `dailymotion`, or `youtube`) and then s/he would enter the `link` of the `video` in the other `input` field.

**Problem**

I'm getting the `type-of-link` and the `link` successfully and so, I'm updating the `post_meta` successfully each time the `type-of-link` and the `link` is changed and the `update` buttons is clicked, **BUT** only when I use  `e.preventDefault()` for the `update` button, when I remove `e.preventDefault()`, then the `post_meta` is not updating, although I have `echo` out the data I'm getting it correctly.

The code is working fine, when I use `e.preventDefault()` for the button, but when I remove `e.preventDefault()`, then the new data is not updating which I'm expecting the code to do so.

**Note**

I have asked the question
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61848343/update-post-meta-is-not-updating-the-data-although-getting-values-correctly)

Please help me, I'm stuck badly :(

Following are the `input fields` of which I'm getting the data.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using AJAX this way? You shouldn't need your own AJAX requests to update custom fields.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Because I want to validate the `link` if it is a `valid` link or not, and then save them in the DB,
what other approach should I use? I'm new to plugin development.